# Creating a combined pandas column for mixed value types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where I want the values starting with ID to be replaced with just 'user/ID' prefix and any leading zeros removed. I want to make a third column where I just get the ID values (no user prefix, no leading zeros, no IDm/IDs, just ID) and the E values on the same row to be combined with an underscore and then add in a 'user/' prefix.
I have an example for reference.
original

```
item_id_a                   item_id_b   
0   E00000170630            IDm00010461 
1   IDm00010461             E00000170630    
2   E00000353915            IDs236274573    
3   IDs23627457             E00000353915
```

desired:

```
item_id_a                   item_id_b                  combined
0   E00000170630            user/ID10461             user/E00000170630_ID10461
1   user/ID10461            E00000170630              user/ID10461_E00000170630
2   E00000353915            user/ID236274573          user/E00000353915_ID236274573            
3   user/ID23627457         E00000353915              user/ID23627457_E00000353915
```

Comment: Ok, so... what's stopping you from doing it? Show what you have tried (ideas, code, anything?). What exactly don't you know how to do? For example, can you write a function that takes a single string and modifies it the way you want? If you had that function, would you know how to apply it to every element in your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(df.replace(r'ID[a-z]?0*','ID',regex=True)
.assign(combined = lambda x: 'user/' + x['item_id_a'] + '_' + x['item_id_b'])
.replace(r'^ID','user/ID',regex=True))
```

Output:

```
         item_id_a         item_id_b                       combined
0     E00000170630      user/ID10461      user/E00000170630_ID10461
1     user/ID10461      E00000170630      user/ID10461_E00000170630
2     E00000353915  user/ID236274573  user/E00000353915_ID236274573
3  user/ID23627457      E00000353915   user/ID23627457_E00000353915
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["combined"] = "user/" + df.item_id_a + "_" + df.item_id_b
df.loc[1::2, "item_id_a"] = "user/" + df.loc[1::2, "item_id_a"]
df.loc[0::2, "item_id_b"] = "user/" + df.loc[0::2, "item_id_b"]
```